# How to force fonts to be same size in px for different resolutions

Tags: java, swing, fonts, font-size

I am working on a Java Swing application that needs to be run on a significant smaller screen size than what it was developed for.

Unfortunately, the layout gets heavily distorted, mainly because the fonts are displaying relatively bigger.

Most of the font sizes are set using embedded html in JLabels and JButtons.

How can I force the font sizes in Swing to be equal in Pixels across different resolutions?

Comment: try this maybe Dimension screenSize =Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int width = (int)screenSize.getWidth();
        int height = (int)screenSize.getHeight();
        jlabel.setFont(new Font(null, Font.BOLD, width/whatever));

Comment: *"Most of the font sizes are set using embedded html in JLabels and JButtons."*  That is the problem that should be fixed.  Everything else is an hack to cover a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Start with [Toolkit(.getToolKit()).getScreenResolution()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getScreenResolution--) as per the javadocs: "Returns the screen resolution in dots-per-inch". Next, create a [FontMetrics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html) `Object` for your screen and `Font` (there are multiple ways to do this). Then you can use FontMetrics.getHeight() with the screen resolution to figure out how big it will display. You can use `Font.deriveFont(float)` until the size is the same or as similar as possible as what you want

Comment: Can I do this in one place or do I have to adjust all Components that use a font?

Comment: Definitely possible to do this in one place going through `GraphicsEnvironment`

Comment: You mean by using getAllFonts() and adjusting all Fonts? BTW, I get the same ScreenResolution() in dpi for different resolutions! So I don't get how that helps me.

Comment: I assumed you just have 1 or 2 `Fonts` you were using; how many `Fonts` are you using in your project? Second, if you are finding that ScreenResolution is always the same, you should find that ScreenSize is also always the same, which is good, because it means that no matter the resolution you set your screen to, your Java app will size accordingly. This is actually what I've always found, but if this isn't what you find, then this would be serious violation from the API contract in Toolkit

Comment: You're right, I'm only using a 1 or 2 fonts. I'm now trying graphicEnv.registerFont(font.deriveFont(0.5)) but this doesn't take. It returns false, presumably because I can't overwrite fonts with this method.

Comment: You have to set the font with the font size on your components using `Component.setFont(...)` If you are using `JComponent`s, you only need to set the Font on the top level container and the Font will propogate